# wp_footer() not load plugin script in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

i have template that include many function file. in `footer.php` file `wp_footer()` load just a menu. how can find which action ruined `wp_footer()` function.

**Edit1:**

I looking for some way to find where action added for wp_footer if it possible.

footer file code:

```
    </div><!-- end wrapper -->

    <!-- END SITE -->



    <?php wp_footer(); ?>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `wp_footer()` loading everything, which are hooked to `wp_footer`. what there must be? what you mean with `ruined `? any errors?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan . I think some action remove any script must load by wp_footer and now just simple html menu load on call wp_footer function.

Comment: Hope you realize how useless for us is the code you shared.. we have no idea of what was done or changed. To such a vague question, all i can answer is: Undo all what you did until it works again.

Comment: @Kaddath. i khow. The problem is that I did not create template.

Comment: I see. try to find something like `add_action('wp_footer', 'some_functions_names');` in all `.php` files and check all functions, or something like `remove_action('wp_footer', 'some_functions_names')`. but it would be fater to disable all plugins and check if the problem caused active theme

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan, Thank you for your help. problem is there is many function file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From our discussion**: *You need to get the list of all functions, which hooked to `wp_footer` action.*

You can use this:

```
add_action('wp', function () {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($GLOBALS['wp_filter']['wp_footer']);
    echo '</pre>';
    exit;
});
```

The code will output all functions in the array, which hooked to `wp_footer` action.

Code goes to the `functions.php` file of active theme/child theme

Comment: Thanks. I looking for this. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get all scripts or css which are loaded in wp_footer by this code.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'list_comment_filters' );
function list_comment_filters()
{
    global $wp_filter;
    $comment_filters = array ();
    $h1  = '<h1>Current Comment Filters</h1>';
    $out = '';
    $toc = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $wp_filter as $key => $val )
    {
        if ( FALSE !== strpos( $key, 'comment' ) )
        {
            $comment_filters[$key][] = var_export( $val, TRUE );
        }
    }
    foreach ( $comment_filters as $name => $arr_vals )
    {
        $out .= "<h2 id=$name>$name</h2><pre>" . implode( "\n\n", $arr_vals ) . '</pre>';
        $toc .= "<li><a href='#$name'>$name</a></li>";
    }
    print "$h1$toc</ul>$out";
}
```

Comment: I khow. but my problem about find actions add to wp_footer.

Comment: Please use this code in functions.php. It will works.

Comment: Thanks. That is what i want.

Answer (score 0):

To load code in `wp_footer()` function you should use `wp_footer` action. Like

```
add_action('wp_footer', function(){ /* your code */ });
```

Find all `wp_footer` actions and check code each of them.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but The problem is that there are many function that require in each other. i looking for some way to find all action that theme add to wp_footer if it possible.